# Batch File to insert char in file name for multiple files in a folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename

I have a series of files that have names like this:

```
CHART_LOAN_6516_20130502.PDF

CHART_LOAN_2158_20130502.PDF

CHART_LOAN_78986_20130502.PDF
```

Each file always starts with CHART_LOAN_ but the next number is different and the last number is the date it was created.

I would like to insert an 0_ after CHART_LOAN_number_ for each file. As listed below:

```
CHART_LOAN_6516_0_20130502.PDF

CHART_LOAN_2158_0_20130502.PDF

CHART_LOAN_78986_0_20130502.PDF
```

Through my research I've found out to insert the char but not when the name is changing with each file.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET old=CHART_LOAN_
SET new=CHART_LOAN_0_
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b *.jpg') do (
  SET newname=%%f
  SET newname=!newname:%old%=%new%!
  move "%%f" "!newname!"
)
```

The above code will change the static portion of the file to something I want, but I don't know how to modify the code to compensate for the changing loan number.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /a-d %old%*.pdf^|find /i /v "%new%"') do (
```

should see you right – but I'd add an `ECHO`  temporarily before the `MOVE` to check it's working properly.

Interesting that you'd use `*.jpg` in your original though. Rather unlikely to work, I'd guess.

The renamed files will match the pattern `..._0_...` but the originals won't – the closest they'll come is with `CHART_LOAN_0.pdf`. Hence, you find all the filenames that *don't* match the new mask (`/v`) case-insensitive (`/i`). The `/a-d` guards against the remote possibility of a directory name that matches the `old` mask. The caret before the pipe tells CMD that the pipe is part of the command to be executed by the `for`.

Comment: I didn't mean to use .jpg in the code, it should have been .pdf

Comment: I took the liberty of brushing up your post a little. Sorry if I've got something wrong and in that case please feel free to roll back or change my edit as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-3*delims=_" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.pdf ^| find /i /v "_0_"') do ren "%%i_%%j_%%k_%%l" "%%i_%%j_%%k_0_%%l"
```

Comment: Note that the numeral after LOAN_ could also be 0 so the find filter may exclude those files.

Comment: But it is a more theoretical option, `loan` should never be `0` :))

Comment: Not loan, the numeral AFTER loan_ :)

Comment: That work great thank you. Now to try to dissect the code and see if I can fully understand it.